# The existence of a non-split composition series in a indecomposable module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Assume that $R$ is a ring with unit and $M$ is a indecomposable left $R$-module with finite length. That is, $M$ has a composition series.

> Is it true that there is a composition series
>   $$\begin{align} 0\subseteq M_1  \subseteq M_2  \subseteq \cdots \subseteq M_n = M\end{align}$$ 
>   such that exact sequence
>   $$\begin{align} 0 \rightarrow  M_i  \rightarrow M_{i+1}   \rightarrow   M_{i+1}/M_i \rightarrow 0 \end{align}$$
>   is non-split for all $i$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  For instance, take $R=M=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ for some field $k$.  Then $M$ has a unique submodule $N$ such that $M/N$ is simple (namely $N=(x,y)$), so any composition series for $M$ must have $M_2=N$.  But any simple submodule of $N$ is a direct summand, since $x$ and $y$ both act trivially on $N$ (so a submodule of $N$ is just a sub-$k$-vector space).  Thus in any composition series of $M$, the inclusion $M_1\to M_2$ must split.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for this prompt and nice counterexample! I have another question: Is it true provided $M$ has simple socle?

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question. On second thought, I seem to understand it should be true if $M$ has simple socle. Thanks anyway!